# While loop - out of memory error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a quick script to anonymise a database by switching the names around, I am using a while loop to do this which is causing an out of memory error (it gets to around 950 records before it crashes) this is part of the code I have:

```
DECLARE @counter INT;
SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter < (SELECT MAX(anonID) FROM anon_PersonChangeData)
BEGIN
    SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
    SET @Upper = ( SELECT MAX(anonID) + 1 FROM anon_PersonChangeData ) ---- The highest random number
    SET @Random = ( SELECT ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0) )

    WHILE @Random = @counter
    BEGIN
        SET @Random = ( SELECT ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0) )
    END

    UPDATE anon_PersonChangeData 
        SET   personNewFirstName = (SELECT personCurrentFirstName FROM anon_PersonChangeData WHERE anonID = @Random)
            , personNewSurname = (SELECT personCurrentSurname FROM anon_PersonChangeData WHERE anonID = @Random)
    WHERE anonID = @counter

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

AnonID IS just an incremented field I am using starting from 1.

This also seems to take a very long time to get to even 950.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest that you provide sample data and desired results to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added a select @counter in the middle of the loop to see what record it got up to, which is what was causing the out of memory error. The code seems to work, it is just quite slow, I ran it fully on the two fields above and it took 7 minutes to finish for 14k records.

Comment: If you're just trying to randomise the order of firstname/lastname in your table, then do it with a set-based operation that assigns each row a row_number randomly and updates it based on that. Of course, you might get cases where the firstname/lastname combination is the same before and after but that is the nature of randomness...

Comment: Essentially that is what I have done, I created a new table using ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ID1 )  - this is the anonID.

Comment: Depending upon your version of SQL Server you could use data masking to anonymise the data.

Comment: Doesn't that just redact parts of the data to non-privileged users? I need this for a testing/training database, so I need to spoof the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY NEW()` will give you a random sequence. This is good enough for you?

```
; with cte as
(
    select  rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()), *
    from    anon_PersonChangeData
) 
update  c1
set personNewFirstName  = c2.personNewFirstName,
    personNewSurname    = c2.personNewSurname 
from    cte c1
    inner join cte c2   on  c1.rn = c2.rn
```

If you want random First & Surname, just `inner join` the cte again and update Surname from the new cte

Comment: That kind of works, but I would like it a bit more random there is always at least 1 record that ends up with the name not being anonymised.

Comment: Actually, this did work with the extra CTE join at the end. took about 20 seconds to run all up, thanks a lot!